# How to update another model field from updateview

Tags: python, django

How can I use the current value of a field in update view to update another field?

I have a model employee. It has a field day_absent and amount_absent which shows the total deduction amount based on how many day_absent.

In update view the can set the day_absent.
When I can back to DetailView, say the day_absent is 1. but the deduction is still 0. I understand that this is because prior to save(), day_absent was still 0 and was changed to 1. So the question is how can i compute whatever is value entered in day_absent before it gets saved?

```
class PayrollTransactionUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    model = t_pay
    template_name = 'payroll/transaction/update.html'
    fields = ['day_absent']


  def post(self,request,pk):
        emp = t_pay.objects.get(pk=pk)
        emp.amt_absent = emp.day_absent * emp.amt_rate
        emp.save()
        return super().post(request)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UpdateView` saves the object in the `form_valid()` method. Look at [this invaluable site](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.1/django.views.generic.edit/UpdateView/#form_valid) when you're using Django class-based views.

So you should override the `form_valid()` method, not the `post()` method:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    emp = form.save(commit=False)
    emp.amt_absent = emp.day_absent * emp.amt_rate
    emp.save()
    self.object = amp
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

Note that saving a field to `Employee` that can easily be calculated from two other fields is not recommended, as it could lead to inconsistent/corrupt data. Since `amt_absent` is just the multiplication of two other fields, why do you need to save it?

Alternatively, looking at what you're actually doing, this does not seem the responsibility of the view. If this is supposed to happen every time an `Employee` is saved, you could do it on the model itself:

```
class Employee(Model):
    ... # fields go here

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        self.amt_absent = self._get_amt_absent()
        super().save(**kwargs)
        # update other models here as well
```

In this situation, you don't need to override anything on the `UpdateView`.

Comment: Before i had the computed data as property in my model. But this model employee, has so many computed fields. This is actually a payroll system i am converting from Visual Foxpro.  see(https://pastebin.com/XbA0T5HT). That is just one of the function to update some fields in this model, there is more. So the problem was, there is so much computation if i just store these fields as property. So what approach do u recommend? btw ur answer works like a charm. Thank you so much and i hope u can help me decide about the approach, this is my first django project and new in programming.

Comment: if it means anything, i dont just multiply the field, it goes to a function from another file (https://pastebin.com/Q8KxTnF0)

Comment: there are also cases where i need to update another class. so is it okay if i do this https://pastebin.com/TFNBcZ8D. Sorry to ask too many question, thats the last one if i am lucky to get an advice

Comment: I updated my answer, it looks like this kind of logic belongs to the model, not the view. You should only do stuff in `form_valid()` that has directly got to do with processing data that comes from the request, e.g. the current logged in user, or the form data. The role of the view is to pass data to the model. The model is responsible for all the business logic.

Comment: i now have this in my model https://pastebin.com/7PPwE4LT and its working exactly how i wanted. I didnt know about this before, i want to learn mode, can you show me some reference where i can learn these techniques? thank you so much Dirk, i learned a lot. really thankful

Comment: The [official django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods) is my first go-to reference. But this kind of technique is more general, read a book on MVC (model-view-controller) programming or general OOP (object-oriented programming) to really understand the "separation of concerns" I'm talking about. It's about organising your code.

Comment: Will do. Thank you so much!

Comment: btw i cant update other model. is it okay i update other model from view like so? (https://pastebin.com/CUGkxr8C)

Comment: why can't you update other model after `super().save()`? Or is there data that comes from the form/view/request that you need to be able to update? In that case, yes, do it in the view.

Comment: Nevermind i got it. I tried to import the other model inside my function which is called in my model's save() method...... and it gets the model and update the fields based on variables used inside that function. Exactly what i needed. I really learned alot. Thank you dirkgroten.